# Rails Solution to give a user a warning that another user is currently editing the same record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like a gem or solution so that if a user navigates to the edit view of a record that another user is already editing, the 2nd user has a simple flash warning that someone else is already editing this record. I don't need any optimistic or pessimistic locking of the record. I was hopping to find a gem that already had a solution for this. If not my line of thinking was:

- Saving a record of the record ID and the user ID to a Activities table in the edit action of the controller.
- Check if there are any other records when navigating to the edit view.
- When the record is updated, or the user navigates away from the page, remove the Activity record.

Potential issue I see:

- Updating that the record is no long being updated if the browser window is closed, or the users computer is turned off (without explicitly navigating away from the page).

Any examples, or points in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an md5 hash of your loaded object(based on all your editable attributes) and the object from database and compare both. If they are not same, then someone changed the object after you loaded the object into memory.

```
Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(<string made of all your editable attributes>)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use redis for that.

mark the type and id of the edited object ("post:23322") as a key and the value would be an array (redis's set) of user ids currently editing the document. 
set an expiry TTL on the key to ensure it doesn't stale out.